# perl store and print grep output with spacing

Tags: perl, grep

Storing grep output with spaces. I wanted to store the output of grep command (with spacing) into variable or array and print it out with the spacing as well.

File containing:

```
### Invoked at: Wed Dec  7 22:24:35 2022 ###
```

Code:

```
my $date = qx(grep -oP "\bInvoked at: \\K[^#]*\d" $file);
print "Date: $date\n";
```

Expected output:

```
Date: Invoked at: Wed Dec  7 22:24:35 2022
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\b` and `\d` should be `\\b` and `\\d`. `qx` literals are like `qq` literals, so `\`, `$` and `@` need to be escaped.

And you should get rid of `\n` in the print statement since the string in `$date` already has one, or remove the one in `$date` using `chomp( $date );`.

You also have a code injection bug in your interpolation of `$file` which could be solved using String::ShellQuote's `shell_quote`.

```perl
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my @cmd = ( "grep", "-oP", '\bInvoked at: \K[^#]*\d', $file_qfn );
my $cmd = shell_quote( @cmd );

my $date = qx($cmd);
die "Can't spawn shell: $!\n" if $? == -1;
die "Shell killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" ) if $? & 0x7F;
die "Shell exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n" ) if $? >> 8;

chomp( $date );

say $date;
```

Better yet, we can avoid the shell, and avoiding building a shell command.

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );

my @cmd = ( "grep", "-oP", '\bInvoked at: \K[^#]*\d', $file_qfn );

my $date = capturex( @cmd );
chomp( $date );

say $date;
```

Buy why run a child process at all?

```perl
use File::Slurper qw( read_text );

my $file = read_text( $file_qfn );

my ( $date ) = $file =~ /\bInvoked at: ([^#]*\d)/
   or die( "Invocation date not found\n" );

say $date;
```